# How can I uninstall Xcode Server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xcode

I'm developing an iOS app that involves running the API on my dev machine. I use [Pow](http://pow.cx) to route the rails stack to http://myapp.dev. I recently set up Xcode Server to test out continuous integration, but it messed up Pow. http://myapp.dev would point to Xcode server instead of my app's backend.

I've since moved the Xcode server onto a different computer in the office and disabled it on my machine, but Pow is still broken. How can I remove it from my dev computer? I've turned off Xcode server, but I can't figure out how to uninstall it so Pow can work again. Using `ps aux` I can see almost 150 processes that have `xcs` in their names.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what fixed this problem, but after the *second* restart, the problem was fixed. In between the first and second reboots, however, I think I tried unloading (using `launchctl`) services which had `xcs`in the name. That had no immediate effect, so I assumed it was not working. After the restart, though, `Pow` was routing correctly.